# Can't execute any sudo command

Tags: linux, sudo

I use wsl changed my visudo and my sudo command isn't working.
how can i unchange visudo config ?

- I can't read/write sudoers / visudo
- Sudo commands i recive this message: 'Sorry, user robz is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/xxxxx' as root on ....'

id info:

```
uid=1000(robz) gid=1000(robz) groups=1000(robz),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev)
```

sudo -l:

```
Matching Defaults entries for robz on ADV23:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User robz may run the following commands on ADV23:
    (ALL : ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/cron start
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/robz/apps/mount_driver.sh
```

Please can some one help-me with this. I would'nt like reinstall wsl.

Solution:
@steeldriver comment:
"You should be able to start your WSL instance as root - see for example How to change default user in WSL Ubuntu bash on Windows 10. You can revert your edits from there"

Comment: You should be able to start your WSL instance as root - see for example [How to change default user in WSL Ubuntu bash on Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816732/how-to-change-default-user-in-wsl-ubuntu-bash-on-windows-10). You can revert your edits from there.

Comment: Thanks so much man, this saved my life.
Thx

Comment: Please add @steeldriver's comment as answer.